# Can't reach webside with pm2

Tags: node.js, web, pm2, hackmd

I am trying to run HackMD (https://github.com/hackmdio/hackmd) project on my laptop with pm2.

I can see the status is online with the command `pm2 show 0` but I cannot open the page with browser with the URL `http://localhost:3306` - it shows 'This site can't be reached'.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

config.json:

```
{
    "development": {
        "domain": "localhost",
        "db": {
            "username": "",
            "password": "",
            "database": "hackmd",
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": "3306",
            "dialect": "mysql"
        }
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution to this question, the owner of project provide docker image on Dockhub https://hub.docker.com/r/hackmdio/hackmd/, build the service with docker is easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I think default port of `mysql` is `3306`.

And you are trying to call on this port while the port is set is `3000` in `./lib/config.json`

[config.js](https://github.com/hackmdio/hackmd/blob/master/lib/config.js)

Try to hit `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Then check your error, there must be something else issue.